# Setup NodaTime under Asp.Net vnext

Tags: asp.net, .net, nodatime, visual-studio-2015, dnx

I've installed VS2015 CTP, created a vNext ConsoleApplication and would like to use NodaTime.

I've added the dependency like so:

```
"dependencies": {
    "NodaTime": "1.3.1"
},
```

The package gets restored, but when I try to compile the solution, a warning arises:

```
Type NodaTime.Instant exists in the package: NodaTime 1.3.1, Supported frameworks: .NETFramework 3.5-Client;.NETPortable-net40+sl50+win+wpa81+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+xamarinios10
```

The type is then simply not found by the compiler, telling me:

```
The type or namespace name 'NodaTime' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Any ideas on how to fix that? Could I also just add it as an dependency of the framework that it exists for?

Comment: Are you listing .Net Core in the frameworks portion of your project.json file? It looks like NodaTime doesn't support .Net Core yet. You can either remove .Net Core or find some other way to implement your project... or wait for Jon Skeet to update NodaTime.

Comment: @MattDeKrey hmmm, okay. I thought so, it's just not out yet for the new .net ... I was just unaware that there is no good way to use the old one automatically. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most existing packages will not support ASP.NET Core 5 yet; because of the significant differences, they need to be manually updated. If you're wanting to use NodaTime, you'll either need to stick to ASP.NET 5 (not Core) or wait for Jon Skeet to release a Core version.

ASP.NET 5 (not Core) will still let you use all the new functionality, though... except not cross platform.

Comment: Rest assured, I'm definitely intending to support .NET Core :) I'm just waiting for things to settle down a bit before building a new release (1.3.2).

Comment: @JonSkeet I was absolutely sure you would, thanks for answering here :)

Comment: @JonSkeet does 1.3.2 support .net core?

Comment: @Alex: No, I'm intending to keep the 1.x line targeting PCLs, and switch to netstandard1.1 for Noda Time 2.0.